# Why passed param with Ajax to controller in ASP.NET Core is always NULL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parameter-passing, asp.net-ajax

It works but the passed parameter is always null, this code is working on my other project on the ASP.NET Framework(.Net Framework) but not working in ASP.NET Core.

```
var inputParams = "{namex: '" + 'testdata' + "'}";

var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "/Test/MyFunction",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: inputParams,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg) {

    },
    error: function (xhr) {

    }
});
```

The Test Controller contains:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult MyFunction(string namex) <--- namex is always NULL
    {
        return Json(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not being sent in the correct format for the content to properly bind to teh action

First construct the payload properly to be posted

```
var inputParams = { namex: "testdata" }; //<-- NOTE JavaScript

var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "/Test/MyFunction",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(inputParams), //<-- NOTE CONVERSION TO JSON
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg) {

    },
    error: function (xhr) {

    }
});
```

Next create a model to hold the data on the server side

```
public class MyModel {
    public string namex { get; set;}
}
```

Finally refactor the action to bind to the expected data from the body of the request

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyFunction([FromBody]MyModel model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        string namex = model.namex;
        return Ok();
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: I found another answer like yours but why should I create a model(MyModel) just to pass a simple variable to my controller, there is no way to do it without creating an extra model?

Comment: @motevalizadeh is that how the actual code is going to be used? I am just suggesting the approach most recommended by documentation for model binding in Asp.Net Core. Review the link provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add FromBodyAttribute to parameter

MyFunction([FromBody] string namex)

Answer (score 0):

just sent it without object

```
var inputParams = 'testdata';

var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "/Test/MyFunction",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: inputParams,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg) {

    },
    error: function (xhr) {

    }
});
```

---

or

---

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "/Test/MyFunction?namex=testdata", // <------ here
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg) {

    },
    error: function (xhr) {

    }
});
```